# Can I compare two dates in Smalltalk?

Tags: date, smalltalk, visualworks

I have two dates which I need to compare, if one is past second. That means:

```
date1 := Date newDay: 10 month: 12 year: 2017
date2 := Date newDay: 1 month: 1 year: 2020
```

So in this case *date2* is past *date1*, so I need this to be **true**.

But

```
date1 := Date newDay: 10 month: 12 year: 2017
date2 := Date newDay: 3 month: 7 year: 2015
```

should return **false.**

Anyone got hints? Appreciate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this depends on which dialect you are using, but ANSI standard already defines `<` for `DateAndTime` which seems similar to `Date`. I tried your code in Pharo and Dolphin and `date1 < date2` works just fine for your needs (even if Date instantiation in Dolphin is a little bit different).